# How do I create a dynamic domain?

Tags: d3.js

How do I refactor this code so that 12 axes are drawn with the correct number of days for each month? So that January has a domain of 1 to 31; February has a domain of 1 to 28 etc.

```
const svg = d3.select("svg"),
  width = +svg.attr("width"),
  height = +svg.attr("height");

const scale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([1, 31]) // The 31 days needs to be dynamic
  .range([0, width - 32]);

const axis = d3.axisBottom(scale)
  .ticks(31); // The 31 ticks needs to be dynamic

svg.selectAll("g")
  .data([31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31])
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", (d, i) => { return "translate(16, " + i * 64 + ")"; })
  .call(axis);
```

Here is a [Codepen](http://codepen.io/24ma13wg/pen/ryvjQp). I'm using version 4 of d3.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the scale and ticks for each axis:

```
const svg = d3.select("svg"),
  width = +svg.attr("width"),
  height = +svg.attr("height");

const axis = d3.axisBottom();

svg.selectAll("g")
  .data([31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31])
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", (d, i) => { return "translate(16, " + i * 64 + ")"; })
  .each(function(d) { 
        var scale = d3.scaleLinear()
                .domain([1, d])
                .range([0, width - 32]);

         axis.scale(scale)
              .ticks(d)(d3.select(this));});
```

Updated [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zZjZGL)

Comment: What does `(d3.select(this))` do?

Comment: The axis generator `axis(context)` requires a selection. `d3.select(this)` creates a selection with the current `<g>` element.